# Anime about a boy and girl who operate a high-tech ship that can fly and go underwater

Tags: story-identification, anime

Anime from '90s about a pirate ship. It's a sci fi. A boy and girl operate the ship that flies and goes underwater to fight evil. I thought it was called "Pirate Ship," but I can't seem to find it.

Either way, I remember that the ship flies in the sky, uses lasers and is very high-tech, despite looking like a flimsy Victorian vessel. The boy is the protagonist and the girl is a daughter of the captain.

Somehow the kids get to the controls and decide to fight the core of the evil forces and win at the end. I very much want to see this again. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a movie or a series? Also, did you actually watch this in the '90s or more recently?

Comment: [Flying Phantom Ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Phantom_Ship) ?